# use tensorflow classify_image.py to classfy png image

Tags: tensorflow

I want to use tensorflow/models/tutorials/image/imagenet/classify_image.py to classify image, but it only support JPEG image. How can I do to use it to classify my image include JPEG and PNG format?

Comment: You should post your code, what you tried. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: the source code is here [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/imagenet/classify_image.py)

Comment: You posted a link to the tensorflow classify_image.py code on github.  I think Vivek Kumar wanted you to share your personal code.

Comment: also, you might want to check out, [this convert based solution on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/71028/batch-converting-png-to-jpg-in-linux)